# Android media meta data retriever slow performance

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i created music player , but i have problem that when i retrieving song title and artist , it takes long time.
here is my code:

```
private void updateListData()
{
    Song song;
    ArrayList<Song> tempSongList = new ArrayList<>();
    MediaMetadataRetriever myRetriever;
    for(int i = 0;i < songsList.size();i++)
    {
       song = songsList.get(i);
        try
        {
            myRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            myRetriever.setDataSource(song.getSongPath());
            song.setTitle(myRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
            song.setArtist(myRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            // release Media Retriever
            myRetriever.release();
            tempSongList.add(song);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    songsList = tempSongList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the songs are stored on the device you should query [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) for the track information.

Comment: Hello @William. I am facing same problem. I am querying mediastore for track name, artist, album etc. But for album art, I am using MetaDataRetriever. It takes a lot of time. What can I do?

Comment: @KhabyLame If the art isn't available through mediastore I'm afraid your only real option is to use MediaMetadataRetriever. The album art may be embedded inside the audio file and mediastore doesn't always seem to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should directly load your songs from external card

Comment: try to use Soundpool :) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

Comment: it will not help, because i need a collection of songs for sending to another activity that displays all the songs playlist